# Bluetooth LE peripheral as GPS in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gps, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to write an iOS app that makes the iDevice behave act as a GPS over bluetooth.
The iDevice will be a bluetooth 'peripheral', and advertise it's location/GPS capabilities to anything scanning it.

I have searched everywhere, without success.
Is there a specific capability UUID for GPS behaviour?
I have no control over the 'central' application on the PC that will be looking for a bluetooth GPS, so I have to fake this behaviour very convincingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of [defined GATT services](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services) on the Bluetooth site.

The service you will need to implement is the [Location and navigation service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.location_and_navigation.xml)